# In Shell script how to assign nested special character using eval to output

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Am trying to assign special charter to a variable which has another variable appended.

```
[root@STAGING scripting]# FILLBLANK=*******
[root@STAGING scripting]# k=1
[root@STAGING scripting]# eval echo  \"\${FILLBLANK$k}\"
***
[root@STAGING scripting]#
```

**How do I assign output to a variable here ?**

```
[root@STAGING scripting]# a=$(eval echo  \"\${FILLBLANK$k}\")
[root@STAGING scripting]# echo $a
= 1 b `echo filledvalue output reference.properties safe.sh sshpass-1.05-
1.el6.x86_64.rpm storefront_properties.sh storefront_properties.sh_bkp 
test.sh
[root@STAGING scripting]#
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I guess you executed `FILLBLANK1=*******` earlier.

Comment: Generally in bash, if you are solving a problem with `eval`, you are doing it wrong.  Tell us what you are trying to accomplish.  There is likely a much better way.

Comment: @Hauke Laging: Yes it was FILLBLANK1 not FILLBLANK, sorry for wrong paste, please suggest solution.

Comment: @John1024        as solution to achieve above is ok for me ,please suggest

Comment: This is my requirement                                                      read -ep "$(eval "echo -e '\e[32m\t\t\tFor Item `echo $z` Enter Value-\e[0m'")$k:" FILLBLANK$k

                                                        filledvalue=$(eval echo "\$FILLBLANK$k")

Comment: I asked you to tell us what you are trying to accomplish __and you haven't done that.__  (Showing us code that does not do what you want is not in any way the same thing as telling us what you want.)  As best I can guess, @ilkkachu's answer is what you need.

Comment: @sudhirtataraju I would suggest [edit]ing your question to tell what you actually are trying to do. I still haven't seen anything that would require the use of `eval`, and I firmly believe there would be better ways to do whatever it is you're doing. Though comments don't support proper formatting, so almost any code in them is rather hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make variables like `foo1`, `foo2` etc. and use `eval` to expand one of them, just *don't*. Bash, ksh and Zsh support arrays and associative arrays, they're made just for indexing. See [BashGuide for an intro on arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays).

```
$ foo[0]=aa
$ foo[1]=bb
$ k=1
$ echo "${foo[$k]}"
bb
```

Note the *quotes* in the above. In fact your issue is also about **quotes**. Not in assigning to `a`, but printing it (really, expanding it for `echo` to print)

```
$ a=*
$ echo "$a"
*
$ echo $a
[big bunch of filenames...]
```

Comment: @ikkachu:     in  my question there  is wrong paste i.e FILLBLANK1 not FILLBLANK and your answer is not satisfying for special character ***********                [root@STAGING ~]# k=1
        [root@STAGING ~]# FILLBLANK1=*******
[root@STAGING ~]# echo "${FILLBLANK[$k]}"

Answer (score 0):

It is quite difficult to help you because you do not describe the real problem but instead show us code which is strange to say the least.

But perhaps this helps you:

```
FILLBLANK1="*******"
FILLBLANK[1]="*******"
k=1
echo "$FILLBLANK1"
echo "${FILLBLANK[1]}"
eval echo  \"\${FILLBLANK$k}\"
a="$(eval echo  \"\${FILLBLANK$k}\")"
echo "$a"
```

Comment: thank u so much its wrkng!!!!  so my mistake was missing double quotes on  a="$(eval echo  \"\${FILLBLANK$k}\")" earlier dying with trying a=$(eval echo  \"\${FILLBLANK$k}\")   n failing.

Comment: @sudhirtataraju No, that's the one location where the quotes are **not** necessary...